# constructor inside a method c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a constructor inside a method that I want to have access at all time

```
//ItemEditor.cpp
#include "ItemContainer.h"       
 void ItemEditor::CreateItem() {

            ItemContainer* wornItems = new ItemContainer();
    }
```

inside of my driver I call my method createItem();

```
//driver
int main(){
    ItemEditor* createItem = new ItemEditor();
        createItem->CreateItem();
}
```

afterwards I want to have access to backpack outside of the createItem

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Make it a member variable?

Comment: and why do you use `new`?

Answer (score 0):

Make the item container a member variable so its scope is the life time of the object.

There is no reason to use dynamic allocation, so just use an instance of the ItemContainer instead of a pointer.

```
#include <iostream>

class ItemContainer {
    int item = 0;
    public:
        void addItem(int i) {
            item = i;
        }
        int getItem() {
            return item;
        }


}; 

class ItemEditor {

    public:
        ItemEditor() {

        }
        void createEditor() {
             wornItems.addItem(3);   
        }
        ItemContainer wornItems;


};


int main() {

    ItemEditor editor;
    int item = editor.wornItems.getItem(); //or some method
    std::cout << item << std::endl;
    editor.createEditor();
     item = editor.wornItems.getItem(); //or some method
    std::cout << item;

    return 0;

}
```

You can also make the container private and use public methods to access its contents.  You can see an example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e966afa6b62f2fd1)

Comment: Do I still let the constructor Itemcontainer* backpack, inside of createItem()?

Comment: No.  The compiler takes care of it by allocating memory on the stack instead of the heap.

Comment: because I am adding data to wornItems of type ItemContainer inside the method createItem()

Comment: it gives me a lot of undeclared identifier

Comment: So, you don't need to create the item inside of createItem().  Just use it.

Comment: Well, you posted simple code, my simple code works. You'll have to declare the item as a class member, and it should be accessible inside the class functions.

Comment: it gives me a lot of undeclared identifier

Comment: I forgot my ItemContainer.h inside my ItemEditor

Comment: I added how to use it in a create function.

Answer (score 0):

By backpack I assume whatever is returned by

```
 createItem->CreateItem();
```

Why not just store it in a pointer since you used the new to allocate the object in a heap?

```
ItemContainer* ItemEditor::CreateItem() {

        return new ItemContainer();
}
```

Main file:

```
int main(){
    ItemEditor* createItem = new ItemEditor();
    ItemContainer* backpack = createItem->CreateItem();
}
```

Also I want to suggest it is a better practice to provide a move semantic for ItemContainer and get rid of pointers. That way you are relying on RAII and stack for object destruction, less risk of memory-leak. Related article: 
http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html

Here is a full compiling code:

```
//Header.h

#include <iostream>

class ItemContainer{
public:
    void sayHello(){
        std::cout << "HulloWorld!\n";
    }
};

class ItemEditor{
public:
    ItemEditor(){};
    ItemContainer* ItemEditor::CreateItem(){
        return new ItemContainer();
    }
};
```

MainFile:

```
//main
#include "Header.h"

int main()
{
    ItemEditor* createItem = new ItemEditor();
    ItemContainer* backpack = createItem->CreateItem();
    backpack->sayHello();
}
```

Comment: Iget the following error:

declaration is incompatible with "<error-type> *ItemEditor::CreateItem()" (declared at line 17 of "c:\Users\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Character\Character\itemEditor.h") Character c:\Users\\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Character\Character\itemEditor.cpp 23

Comment: @Puzzle Added a working code. I guess you made some typo in your code?